# How to setup different environment (QA,UAT,PROD) in soap ui free version

Tags: soapui

How to setup different environment (QA,UAT,PROD) in soap ui free version for soap request?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up different projects. A workaround is to use your DEV or QA as template. The project file is XML so you can find/replace the hostname or IP address and make different project files for the different envs. I did it this way for years.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to parameterize everything that is unique to each environment: server endpoint, database connect string, username, ..., etc.

You will then have to assign Project level parameter to each, and use [Property Expansion](https://www.soapui.org/docs/scripting-and-properties/property-expansion/) for each one of these.

At runtime, if you are running from [command line](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/running-from-command-line/functional-tests/) or from [Maven](https://www.soapui.org/docs/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x/) you will have to pass in the correct values for each variable.